# Get the indexpath from custom button in accessoryView of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UISearchController` with a separate `UITableViewController` as its `searchResultsController`.

```
class SearchResultsViewController: UITableViewController {

    var fruits: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    @objc func addFruit(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let point = tableView.convert(sender.bounds.origin, to: sender)
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)
        print(indexPath?.row)
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fruits.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = fruits[indexPath.row]
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        let addButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        addButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44)
        addButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "add"), for: .normal)
        addButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addFruit(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        addButton.sizeToFit()
        cell.accessoryView =  addButton

        return cell
    }

}
```

I need to show a custom button in cells that search results are shown. So I added a `UIButton` as the cells' `accessoryView`. And it looks and works fine.

[image]

Now I need to get the cell's `indexPath` when the user taps on this button.

I'm trying to get it like shown below.

```
@objc func addFruit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let point = tableView.convert(sender.bounds.origin, to: sender)
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)
}
```

But it keeps returning `nil` for every cell.

Is there any other way to get the `indexPath` from a custom button tap? I added a [demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lqnmkr5tqnvxhlj/CustomSearchCellDemo.zip?dl=0) here as well.

Comment: try `let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? CustomTableViewCell
        let indexPath = tblView.indexPath(for: cell!)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom class named `SOButton` and add variable of type `IndexPath` to it. Use this class for your add button initialisation.

```
//Your class will look like - 

class SOButton: UIButton {
   var indexPath: IndexPath?
}

//Your action will look like -

@objc func addFruit(_ sender: SOButton) {
     print(sender?.indexPath.row)
}

//And in your cellForRow add

let addButton = SOButton(type: .custom)
addButton.indexPath = indexPath
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 2):

Please update your code. you pass the UIButton sender in convert function , please pass the tableView into them

```
func getIndexPathByCgPoint(_ sender: UIButton) -> IndexPath? {
    let point = sender.convert(sender.bounds.origin, to: tableview)
    guard let indexPath = tableview.indexPathForRow(at: point) else {
        return nil
    }
    return indexPath
}
```

But in case of section header it return nil.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let buttonPosition =  sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
 let currentIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
```

Try this it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this light solution: add indexPath.row to button tag:

```
let addButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
addButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44)
addButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

And in button action:

```
@objc func addFruit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(sender.tag)
}
```